# Django Next Parameter Redirect - Adding Additional Parameters

Tags: django, redirect, get, django-views, parameter-passing

I'm trying to add authentication to my webapp. A user begins the authentication process by going to:

```
/authorization/v1/new?client_id=X&response_type=Y&redirect_uri=Z
```

If `request.user` does not exist, I redirect using the following code:

```
try:
    user_identity = Identity.objects.get(user=request.user)
except:
    resource = '%s?next=/authorization/v1/new' % settings.LOGIN_URL
    return HttpResponseRedirect(resource)
```

This takes the user to `/login/?next=/authorization/v1/new`.

The user logs in successfully, and is redirected back to `/authorization/v1/new`.

**However**, now I'm missing the required GET parameters `client_id`, `response_type`, and `redirect_uri`, and this causes the authorization endpoint to throw an error for missing required parameters.

***What is the best way to capture the initial GET params, pass them through to login, and attach them to the redirection back to the auth endpoint?***

I thought about using sessions or modifying the `redirect_uri` to attach the other params, but I still need to figure out how to capture a single parameter through this process.  I'd like to not have to modify the login code, if possible.  Any ideas/suggestions greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You say "If `request.user` is anonymous, I redirect to:"; are you accomplishing this with `@login_required`, or something custom?

Comment: Nope, I try to lookup a UserProfile with a FK to user via `request.user`, and if it throws an exception I redirect them back to the login URL with the next path added.

Comment: Always a good idea to post the relevant code. In this case, you'll get better answers if you post the code that actually does the redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were using Django's built-in `@login_required` decorator, I believe this would be taken care of for you [as of r2954](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/849).

Given that you're not, you just need to replicate the same steps. Just set `next` to the value of the full path (as [Django does in `@login_required`](https://github.com/django/django/commit/be57a7fd1a)), like so:

```
from urllib import quote

...
    try:
        user_identity = Identity.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except Identity.DoesNotExist:   
        return HttpResponseRedirect('%snext=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, quote(request.get_full_path()))
```

*NB* I've also changed your code to avoid your [Pokémon exception handling](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) ("Gotta catch 'em all!").

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I was unaware of the fine details of login_required; it helped to look through Django's committed documentation for this change.  Thank you for clearing this up!